# Content Editor search is not working for the template Ids

Tags: solr, content-search

I have `Sitecore 10.3 with SOLR` search. In the `"Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config"` I have mentioned the `<indexAllFields>false</indexAllFields>` and next add the what are the template i need to index in the `AddIncludedTemplate` section. After all rebuild the index i'm trying to search the Id in the content Editor which is mentioned in the IncludedTemplate section result is not coming.

Example: I'm trying to search the ID `{1930BBEB-7805-471A-A3BE-4858AC7CF696}` this is a standard Template id but the result shows different.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you check this in the Solr Dashboard? Apply query like - _template: 1930bbeb7805471aa3be4858ac7cf696 and see if results are coming there in solr dashboard.

Comment: No result in dashbaord

Comment: Have you tried https://www.skillcore.net/sitecore/sitecore-custom-search-options-for-content-editor ?

Comment: This also not working,

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to showconfig in CMS https://yourinstancename/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx
   and check that {1930BBEB-7805-471A-A3BE-4858AC7CF696} is added under (if not add the config).
2. Then, Try **Populate Solr Managed Schema** and then do index rebuild on **Indexing manager**.